# Jquery Ajax error

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to do an ajax Call using jquery in one of my webpages.

It's going into Error function all the time.
When I look at the console in Firebug, the status seems to be ok , it displays 200 OK.

And when I manually launch the url in a firefox window, i am getting the expected page.

But when the same url is being called through jquery ajax, it always goes into the error function.

Following are the various values that i got during debug
xhr.readyState=4
xhr.statusText=Error
xhr.responseBody=undefined.

Could anyone of you please help me with this ?

```
function ajax_call(urlString)
        {
            ret_val="";
            $.ajax
            (
                {
                    type: "GET",
                    url: urlString,
                    async:false,
                    cache:false,
                    success: function(msg)
                    {
                        ret_val=msg;
                    },
                    error:function (xhr, textStatus, thrownError)
                    {
                        ret_val=xhr.readyState;
                        alert("textStatus=" +textStatus);
                    }
                }
            );
            return ret_val;
        }
```

Comment: @nunu you need the (), I can't see any issue with the javascript code itself maybe its an issue with the URL your requesting?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

But adding 

    dataType: 'text'

didnt help. I am getting the same error.

And also , the url that I am requesting is in the same domain, infact the php call is being made to the same php, with different set of parameters.

It's not the issue with URL, as if i launch the url manually in another firefox window, request goes through without any problem

Do you guys see any other reason why i am getting an ajax Error

Comment: Hi Ravi, .... it's not entering into the ajax:success function at all. It always goes into the ajax:error function. So alert(msg) will not show anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my mistake !

In the browser URL , i was looking at 
"http://localhost/data.php"

in the AJAX call , i was calling the same php by giving absolute url like
"http://xyz.com/data.php"

as a result, ajax call was considering this as a cross domain call, although it was for the same php.

Resolved this by calling the relative url
"/data.php"

Comment: Yeah, this cross-domain policy is tricky for web newbies (like me) since we see a 200 OK and no clue why it's not working !

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you might be returning plaintext from your call, looking at the jQuery docs for ajax it says the dataType parameter defaults to:

```
dataType                                         String
Default: Intelligent Guess (xml, json, script, or html)
```

That seems to imply that it won't "guess" at plaintext, so maybe try adding

```
dataType: 'text'
```

(assuming you *are* returning plaintext - if not I'll delete this) to your parameters.

---

Also, just to confirm, the URL you are requesting is on the same server as the javascript making the request, isn't it?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

But adding 

    dataType: 'text'

didnt help. I am getting the same error.

And also , the url that I am requesting is in the same domain, infact the php call is being made to the same php, with different set of parameters.

It's not the issue with URL, as if i launch the url manually in another firefox window, request goes through without any problem

Do you guys see any other reason why i am getting an ajax Error